# Insert same timestamp in two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to insert the same timestamp in two tables.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (id, value, time) VALUES (NULL, 'test', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
INSERT INTO table2 (id, time, user) VALUES (NULL, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'username')
```

Basically, the problem is that it's not guaranteed that the time from table1 will be the exact same from table2.

I could, of couse, select a timestamp and then use it in INSERT statements, like in this pseudo-code:

```
$time = $db->query("SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")->fetch_rows()[0];
$db->query("INSERT INTO table1 (id, value, time) VALUES (NULL, 'test', '".$time."')");
$db->query("INSERT INTO table2 (id, time, user) VALUES (NULL, '".$time."', 'username')");
```

My question is: Is there a better solution?

Thanks

Comment: assign it to a variable  is ok (you can do it in mysql as well)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is always a better solution.

But if your applications really depend on the same timestamp, then you'd be better off determining it within your PHP code and then using this in your `INSERT` statements.

```
$time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$db->query("INSERT INTO table1 (id, value, time) VALUES (NULL, 'test', '".$time."')");
$db->query("INSERT INTO table2 (id, time, user) VALUES (NULL, '".$time."', 'username')");
```

You can of course retrieve the timestamp from your db server if necessary, like your example shows, too.

There are other solutions, like using a trigger and such, but in my eyes in most cases this only complicates it without a real benefit.

Comment: That works and its definitely better. I could also use `FROM_UNIXTIME` with unix time, since the timestamp sometimes is weird and doesn't accept a valid date format like you did.